# autopopulate form object from another page/form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am designing a jquery form using "jquery-interdependecies-master."  This form needs to be able to receive data from another form on a different page (same site). So one form bounces off a PHP and populates that data into the textarea field on a form on another page.  I have no idea where to start.  I cannot use html 5.

Comment: I think a javascript setinterval is in order. Use that wrapped around your xml request. Maybe both forms need this interval? idk if you are submitting manually one or not. Perhaps a keyup/down event to trigger the xml request instead of an interval?

Comment: What if you stored that variable data in a session?

http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

It cannot work in html.  PHP with code below.

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```